# Import statments when using Tensorflow contrib keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a bunch of code written using Keras that was installed as a separate pip install and the import statements are written like `from keras.models import Sequential`, etc..

On a new machine, I have Tensorflow installed which now includes Keras inside the *contrib* directory.  In order to keep the versions consistent I thought it would be best to use what's in *contrib* instead of installing Keras separately, however this causes some import issues.

I can import Keras using `import tensorflow.contrib.keras as keras` but doing something like `from tensorflow.contrib.keras.models import Sequential` gives **ImportError: No module named models**, and `from keras.models import Sequential` gives a similar **ImportError: No module named keras.models**.

Is there a simple method to get the `from x.y import z` statements to work? If not it means changing all the instances to use the verbose naming (ie.. `m1 = keras.models.Sequential()`) which isn't my preferred syntax but is do-able.

Answer (score 2):

Try this with recent versions of tensorflow:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import LSTM, TimeDistributed, Dense, ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `tensorflow.contrib.keras.python.keras`:

```
from tensorflow.contrib.keras.python.keras.models import Sequential
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `from tensorflow.contrib.keras.python.keras.models import Sequential` no longer works.  It looks like they are changing the interface as of version 1.4 (currently at RC0).  There is a note saying the `tensorflow.contrib.keras` interface is deprecated and you should use `tensorflow.keras` but this doesn't work either without *python* in the line.

The following did work for me under V1.4rc0

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
import tensorflow.python.keras
import tensorflow.contrib.keras as keras
```

The following did not...

```
import tensorflow.python.keras as keras
```

Hopefully this gets cleaned up a bit more before final release.

Comment: I would be interested to know if you think I should post this behavior as a bug on Github.  It seems like one to me but maybe to someone more familiar with the tensorflow import interface, this is expected.

Comment: `tensorflow.python` is not meant to be exposed for the public from the begining anyway. It is just inside stuff, using it is wrong practice, now tensorflow finally fixes it, you should use `tensorflow.keras`, which is mapped to `tensorflow.python.keras`, directly instead.