# Import Keras directly or through TensorFlow? Should I uninstall either one?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, installation, python-import, tf.keras

I have some working Python3 sources gotten from the internet where initial Keras imports are ***direct*** like this:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
...
```

In TensorFlow documentation instead I see the following ***indirect*** form:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
...
```

To me they seem to mean respectively, that Keras can be used without knowing that TensorFlow is behind, and, that Keras is provided (again?) as a part of TensorFlow. (I kind of expect that also Keras similarly provides references to TensorFlow in the former case)

**What is the difference? Does it depend on how Keras and TensorFlow are installed, or rather on the way they are used? Is it a potential source of confusion that I have to get rid of? In other words, should I fix my installation, and how? Or should I just accept that there are two, and manage their respective usages to live with them safely?**

Background: my installation is under Ubuntu Linux, with Python3.5.2, where `pip3 list` shows the following packages:

```
Keras (2.2.4)
Keras-Applications (1.0.6)
Keras-Preprocessing (1.0.5)
tensorboard (1.12.0)
tensorflow (1.12.0)
```

BTW, I have checked that they are really different:

```
import keras as keras
import tensorflow.keras as tf_keras
print( keras is tf_keras )
---> False
print( [keras.__version__ , tf_keras.__version__] )
---> ['2.2.4', '2.1.6-tf']
print( [len(dir(keras)) , len(dir(tf_keras)) ] )
---> [32, 30]
print( [ len(dir(keras.models)) , len(dir(tf_keras.models)) ] )
---> [27, 17]
print( [ len(dir(keras.layers)) , len(dir(tf_keras.layers)) ] )
---> [167, 117]
```

and indeed it seems that I have two different Keras and that the former is higher versioned and richer.

Related readings, useful but not enough to solve the "does it need a fix?" question:

- [Import statments when using Tensorflow contrib keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46862722/import-statments-when-using-tensorflow-contrib-keras)
- [what's the difference between "import keras" and "import tensorflow.keras"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54913830/whats-the-difference-between-import-keras-and-import-tensorflow-keras)
- [Difference between Keras and tf.keras: should old Keras code be changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54083955/difference-between-keras-and-tf-keras-should-old-keras-code-be-changed)
- [Why keras does not allow to add a convolutional layer in this way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53821855/why-keras-does-not-allow-to-add-a-convolutional-layer-in-this-way/53821915#53821915)

Thanks!

Comment: I agree it is confusing to have the option to import keras or tf.keras.  For my part, I only installed tensorflow and it seems to have come with both as part of the install (via conda). I am also unclear on which I should go with.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than posting my own answer, I'll point you to a very exhaustive answer, much better than I would be able to write: it is [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/10/21/keras-vs-tf-keras-whats-the-difference-in-tensorflow-2-0/) (thanks to [Adrian Rosebrock](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/author/adrian/)).

Disclaimer: I have no link with Adrian or his activity. I have greatly appreciated his explanation though.

Answer (score 0):

There is no fix needed. They're two different packages and you just manage their respective usages.

Answer (score 0):

Official word as of September 2021:

> User should always use `from tensorflow import keras` which will give them the public API.
>
> `import keras` will directly access the `keras` PIP package, which is not 100% same as the public API namespace. It will probably give you `keras.Model/layers.*` etc, but not all the APIs. Under the hood, we populate all the APIs under `keras/api/*` and `tensorflow` `__init__` files will pick them up from there.

https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/keras-project-moved-to-new-repository-in-https-github-com-keras-team-keras/1999/10